# How to test the seemingly "untestable" in Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec2

I'm writing a gem to wrap the xmpp4r RubyGem. I want to add tests for everything I can, but I'm new to testing and a little stuck here.

Essentially, I want one of my classes to have a 'connect' function, but I have no idea whatsoever how to test such a thing...all the examples I can find online about testing are over-simplified. it "is green broccoli", etc., you get the idea.

How can you test something seemingly more complex? Links to good documentation on this stuff would be nice, as well as more personalized answers from your own experience.

EDIT: Possibly letting the test pass if it doesn't encounter any exceptions? Would I be on the right path by doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Just remember you as a programer, you are the lord of your own code world.

The same way you build applications easy to use for others, you can help yourself and make your code easy to test. One of the main benefits of doing OO programming is that it will encapsulate behaviours into methods, then is easier to test your code using those methods as key testing points. If your code is hard to test, it is becuase you are not seeing yourself or the tester as another user of you application/code.

Testing is not directly related to any framework or technology.
Try to see it as something separated from the code itself, something bigger than that.
If you do not know how to test something is because you most probably do not know why you need it and how it is going to be used.

Try doing some TDD (Test Driven Development) and you will get my point.

Also keep in mind there are different types of testing:
Functional testing / High Level
Unit test / Low Level
UAT / User Acceptance Testing
Performance Testing 
Exploratory Testing / Hand testing
Integration testing (you can build some mockups of the pieces that you code will work with to anticipate any problem prior the integration)

Testing is expensive, so it is not a matter to test everything is about test what needs to be tested.

Even the NASA do not test "everything"

Testing is ...deep as programming.
Nice dive!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testability

Comment: I like your style of a general overview. While I was looking for more directed advice, your reply was very informative and I am definitely taking into consideration what you posted. Thank you for your time and effort in making it a little more clear for me!

Answer (score 2):

First, check if the gem itself is tested. If it is and tests are passing, you should probably trust the gem's code. Then, you can just mock any calls to the gem and return the appropriate calls when testing for success or failure scenarios.

i.e.

```
xmpp4r.should_receive(:connect).and_return(mock("xmpp4r"))
```

If the gem is not tested, it's about the same as you didn't have any tests yourself. You should consider using another gem or testing it yourself (or even create one using TDD).

Comment: This was very concise and to-the-point, and although I'd read this before, it had slipped my mind, so this is a nice reminder about this aspect of the whole thing. Thank you very much!